# Nuspec files from nested directory

Tags: nuget, target, nuspec

I have such file structure:

> MyProject/MyProject/bin

I am creating Nuget package via nuspec file. So to add bin folder, I have added this command:

```
<file src="MyProject/MyProject/bin/**" target="bin"/>
```

But as a result I am receiving this file structure:

> bin/MyProject/MyProject/bin

Is there a way to copy files directly into bin folder, without creating nested directories? So my output would be like simple:

> bin

Comment: You may need to change the forward slash into a backslash instead. I usually use it as "MyProject\MyProject\bin\*" and this works perfectly fine outputting to just a bin folder.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you ! :)